# How to keep excel formula consistent with inserting new columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, insert

In my sheet, my top row is a bunch of dates and I have columns separating the weeks.

```
| 1.1 | 1.5 | 1.12 | 1.29 |JANUARY TOTAL| 2.3 | 2.15 | FEBRUARY TOTAL|
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below each date is the number of hours worked on a project, and in each "MONTH TOTAL" column is a sum of the time worked on each project per month.

When I created this spreadsheet, I put in a filler of 2 blank spaces, but since I can't predict when I'll be working on each project, I have to rely on inserting new columns if I decide to work on something on a day that isn't preset into the sheet.

The problem is that my formulas don't extend all the way to the MONTH TOTAL columns when I insert new columns. For instance, when I create my spreadsheet, my formula for one of the totals in the MONTH TOTAL column would be "=SUM(B2:C2)" but when I insert two more dates I need the formula to be "=SUM(B2:E2)".

Is there a way to encapsulate inserted cells into a formula so that it sums between a bound of two columns and any new inserted cells?

Comment: I'd honestly arrange the data in a columnar fashion and use a pivot table. You only need to adjust the data source and the pivot table will update. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Bat.png).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INDIRECT` function coupled with `ADDRESS`, `ROW`, and `COLUMN`.

In your stated example, let's assume your "MONTH TOTAL" formula is in `D2` and currently contains `=SUM(B2:C2)`.  You will want to update the formula to:

> `=SUM(B2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))`

Whenever you insert a new column, it will still SUM by referencing the values in the preceding columns.

Comment: Thank you! This works great! If I were to add something set up the formula for the rest of the months of the year, and I add a column in any arbitrary month, will it offset any of the starting dates of any months afterward? For instance, the formula for March would be "=SUM(F2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))", but then I add a column to February. Would that formula be incorrect and need to be changed to "=SUM(G2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))"?

Comment: Hi @Toblor.  If you insert a new column, the formulas should automatically update.  `F2` will become `G2`.